# How to Join two SELECT queries having same column names but different row values in both tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, logic

I got a table from SELECT Query 1 as below from SQL Server:

| NUMBER | NAME | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 21 | Name1 | 20.03.2004 |
| 25 | Name2 | 26.06.2005 |
| 23 | Name3 | 26.06.2005 |
| 24 | Name4 | 22.04.2012 |

I got a table from SELECT query 2 as below from SQL Server:

| NUMBER | NAME | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 30 | Name10 | 20.03.2064 |
| 30 | Name10 | 26.06.2035 |
| 35 | Name30 | 26.06.2025 |
| 36 | Name40 | 22.04.2042 |

I want to join these SELECT queries into one SELECT query like below:

| NUMBER | NAME | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 21 | Name1 | 20.03.2004 |
| 25 | Name2 | 26.06.2005 |
| 23 | Name3 | 26.06.2005 |
| 24 | Name4 | 22.04.2012 |
| 30 | Name10 | 20.03.2064 |
| 30 | Name10 | 26.06.2035 |
| 35 | Name30 | 26.06.2025 |
| 36 | Name40 | 22.04.2042 |

I tried like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT Number,Name,Date FROM table1 ) t1
INNER JOIN ( SELECT Number, Name, Date FROM table2) t2
ON t1.number = t2.number
```

But it didn't work, This is not a actual table I want to join.

Basically I want to join two SELECT Query who got same Column names but have no common values between them.
And I want to use SELECT query from the joined table.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: try `UNION` 
just like this  `Query1 UNION Query2;`

Comment: Or perhaps `UNION ALL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UNION` and `UNION ALL` are SQL operators used to concatenate 2 or more result sets. This allows us to write multiple `SELECT` statements, retrieve the desired results, then combine them together into a final, unified set.

The main difference between `UNION` and `UNION ALL` is that:

**UNION:** only keeps unique records
**UNION ALL:** keeps all records, including duplicates

#### UNION Example:

```
SELECT column1 AS datacheck from table1 
  UNION 
SELECT column1 AS datacheck from table2
```

**Result:**

```
+-----------+
| datacheck |
+-----------+
|   data2   |
+-----------+
```

#### UNION ALL example:

```
SELECT column1 AS datacheck from table1 
  UNION ALL
SELECT column1 AS datacheck from table2
```

**Result:**

```
+-----------+
| datacheck |
+-----------+
|   data2   |
|   data2   |
+-----------+
```

Answer (score 4):

```sql
    SELECT Number, Name, Date FROM table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Number, Name, Date FROM table2
```

Comment: For those with a WHERE statement in the query. Here is an example:

    SELECT Number, Name, Date FROM table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Number, Name, Date FROM table2
    WHERE Number = 1;

It is important to notice that there is only one WHERE statement at the end of the query.
It gets more complex if you are joining other tables in the queries.

Answer (score 0):

For those that need a WHERE statement in the query. Here is an example:

```
SELECT Number, Name, Date FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT Number, Name, Date FROM table2
WHERE Number = 1;
```

It is important to notice that there is only one WHERE statement at the end of the query.
It gets more complex if you join other tables in the queries and, for example, need to GROUP BY and/or ORDER BY. The GROUP BY statement goes in each SELECT query being UNION, and it has to be identical. The ORDER BY however can only go with the WHERE statement. Here is an example.

```
SELECT DISTINCT I.idInstruments ,IAC.Inst_Model, Instrument_Serial,M.Manufacturer_Name,CI.Company_Name,CI.Company_Physical_Address1,CI.Company_Physical_Address2,CI.Company_Physical_City,CI.Company_Physical_State,
CI.Company_Physical_County,CI.Company_Physical_ZipCode,CustI.Customer_FirstName,CustI.Customer_MiddleName,CustI.Customer_LastName,CustI.Customer_Telephone,CustI.Customer_CellPhone
FROM service_call SC
LEFT JOIN system_info SI ON SC.idSystem_Info=SI.idSystem_Info
LEFT JOIN instruments I ON I.idInstruments=SC.IDInstruments0 OR I.idInstruments=SC.IDInstruments1 OR I.idInstruments=SC.IDInstruments2 OR I.idInstruments=SC.IDInstruments3 OR
I.idInstruments=SC.IDInstruments4 OR I.idInstruments=SC.IDInstruments5 OR I.idInstruments=SC.IDInstruments6 OR I.idInstruments=SC.IDInstruments7 OR I.idInstruments=SC.IDInstruments8 OR I.idSystem_Info=SI.idSystem_Info
LEFT JOIN customer_info CustI ON SC.idCustomer_Info=CustI.idCustomer_Info
LEFT JOIN company_info CI ON I.idCompany_Info=CI.idCompany_Info
LEFT JOIN inst_acc_models IAC ON I.idInst_Models=IAC.idInst_Models
LEFT JOIN manufacturers M ON IAC.idManufacturers=M.idManufacturers
GROUP BY I.Instrument_Serial
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT I.idInstruments ,IAC.Inst_Model, Instrument_Serial,M.Manufacturer_Name,CI.Company_Name,CI.Company_Physical_Address1,CI.Company_Physical_Address2,CI.Company_Physical_City,CI.Company_Physical_State,
CI.Company_Physical_County,CI.Company_Physical_ZipCode,CustI.Customer_FirstName,CustI.Customer_MiddleName,CustI.Customer_LastName,CustI.Customer_Telephone,CustI.Customer_CellPhone
FROM service_call_archives SC
LEFT JOIN system_info SI ON SC.idSystem_Info=SI.idSystem_Info
LEFT JOIN instruments I ON I.idInstruments=SC.IDInstruments0 OR I.idInstruments=SC.IDInstruments1 OR I.idInstruments=SC.IDInstruments2 OR I.idInstruments=SC.IDInstruments3 OR
I.idInstruments=SC.IDInstruments4 OR I.idInstruments=SC.IDInstruments5 OR I.idInstruments=SC.IDInstruments6 OR I.idInstruments=SC.IDInstruments7 OR I.idInstruments=SC.IDInstruments8 OR I.idSystem_Info=SI.idSystem_Info
LEFT JOIN customer_info CustI ON SC.idCustomer_Info=CustI.idCustomer_Info
LEFT JOIN company_info CI ON I.idCompany_Info=CI.idCompany_Info
LEFT JOIN inst_acc_models IAC ON I.idInst_Models=IAC.idInst_Models
LEFT JOIN manufacturers M ON IAC.idManufacturers=M.idManufacturers
WHERE  I.IsDeleted=0 AND I.BeingCreated=0 GROUP BY I.Instrument_Serial ORDER BY Company_Name;
```

I hope it helps somebody :)